# How to run child directive's ajax call only after parent's ajax call

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have been searching a lot for answers for this but I haven't found any.

Let's say I have two different directives which gathers different kind data for two different variables. In other words.

```
<directive-one variable1="xxxx" variable2="yyyy"></directive-one>
<directive-two variable1="xxxx" variable2="yyyy"></directive-two>
```

They look something like this:

```
.directive('directiveOne', [function(){
    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: {
           variable1: "@",
           variable2: "@"
       },
       controller: ["$scope", "$http",
                   function($scope, $http){
                       $http.get("data1/url", {params: {variable1: $scope.variable1, variable2: $scope.variable2}})
                            .success(function(data){
                                $scope.data = data;
                            });
       }],
       template: '<div>{{data}}</div>'
    }
}])
```

Now let's say that xxxx is a id of an object which we want to find by using a search endpoint. And yyyy is a id of an other object which we also want to find by using a search endpoint.

If we would change the directives to:

```
 <directive-one search-variable1="ccccc" search-variable2="ddd"></directive-one>
 <directive-two search-variable1="ccccc" search-variable2="ddd"></directive-two>
```

And create a logic in the controller which first converts the search-variable to a id through an api call and then gathers the data. We would end up making 6 API calls in total.

Can I somehow do this?

```
 <variable-one-searcher search-variable1="cccc">
     // Inside here we have variable1 = "xxxx"
     <variable-two-searcher search-variable2="dddd">
        // Inside here we have variable2 = "yyyy" and variable1 = "xxxx"
        <directive-one></directive-one>
        <directive-two></directive-two>
     </variable-two-searcher>
 </variable-one-searcher>
```

I have tried a lot of combinations with preLink-functions and transcludes and stuff, but I have never got it to work.

Since directiveOne needs to do an API-call which depends on another API-call we need to wait for the parent's API-call to finished. How do you implement that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to use directives? Will you use this multiple times in your application or in other applications? You can probably avoid using id. But, in `variable-one-searcher` directive set it in your controller and require this directive in your `directive-one` and execute inside the link function. In directives, controllers get executes from parent to childrens, link functions from childrens to parents

Comment: You can also use $scope.$broadcast or $scope.$emit for siblings directives communication

Comment: @gr3g yes. I want to give the compiled file to other people which they can include in their angular application/standalone and there will be lot's of directives which need variable1. To always rewrite this part feels hacky! I don't really want to require that the directive-one REQUIRES to be inside a searcher since you may have the id directly

Comment: then you can set an optional require ´?variableOneSearcher´ in check in the logic of your link function if it exist, so you handle both senarios

Comment: with ' xxxx is a id of an object ' you mean DOM element?

Comment: @gr3g didn't know that! But what means require really? Whant difference does it? The order they get's executed? And can I optional require two different directives? I mean sometimes you may know variable1 but you want to search for variable2

Comment: @gr3g No I mean id of a database-object (in the API)

Comment: I'm sure you can make this easier, but I should understand your use case. Anymay: Require: when you create a directive you can add a controller function and a link function. The controller function is meant  for 'public'  communication trough directives. The link function is for your directive. When you require a directive, you say Hey directive, give me your controller. So requiring directive means access controller.

Comment: You can require multiple directives by passing an array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506827/using-multiple-directives-in-require-with-angularjs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Collecting multiple get requests into json array and then passing to directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644047/angularjs-collecting-multiple-get-requests-into-json-array-and-then-passing-to)